# Why 404 error comes out when distributed to spring boot war

Tags: amazon-ec2

There is no problem with Springboot gradle Eclipse, but 404 errors appear when you distribute the server in war format. Help me.
"The requested resource [/] is not available"

```
shoppingmall
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── war-tracker
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   ├── application.properties
    │   ├── com
    │   │   └── example
    │   │       └── demo
    │   │           ├── controller
    │   │           │   ├── CartController.class
    │   │           │   ├── MailServiceRestController.class
    │   │           │   ├── ProductController.class
    │   │           │   └── UserController.class
    │   │           ├── dto
    │   │           │   ├── ProductDTO.class
    │   │           │   └── UserDTO.class
    │   │           ├── mapper
    │   │           │   ├── MailServiceInter.class
    │   │           │   ├── ProductMapper.class
    │   │           │   └── UserMapper.class
    │   │           ├── service
    │   │           │   ├── CartService.class
    │   │           │   ├── EmailService.class
    │   │           │   ├── ProductService.class
    │   │           │   └── UserService.class
    │   │           └── ShoppingmallApplication.class
    │   ├── Config
    │   │   ├── Crypt.class
    │   │   ├── MailConfig.class
    │   │   └── webconfig.class
    │   ├── mapper
    │   │   ├── ProductMapper.xml
    │   │   └── UserMapper.xml
    │   └── static
    │       ├── csc.html
    │       ├── css
    │       │   ├── cart.css
    │       │   ├── MyPageStyle.css
    │       │   ├── product_detail.css
    │       │   ├── responsive.css
    │       │   └── style.css
    │       ├── images
    │       ├── js
    │       │   ├── jquery-1.11.0.min.js
    │       │   ├── modernizr.js
    │       │   ├── plugins.js
    │       │   ├── product_detail.js
    │       │   └── script.js
    │       ├── readme.txt
    ├── lib
    ├── views
    │   ├── index.jsp
    └── web.xml
```

It's the directory structure of ec2.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ShoppingmallApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ShoppingmallApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ShoppingmallApplication.class);
    }
}
```

local : java 17 tomcat 9
server : openjdk 11.0.20 javac 17.0.8 tomcat 9

I changed the file structure and changed the application.properties setting.